# Sybase: How can I use "Select into" statement if I am not sure if the table always have rows or not

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I need to use the `select into` statement:

**Query**

```
Select * into table2 from table1
```

This statement works perfectly if I have rows in the table1. However, in my case sometimes I might have rows in table1 while other times I don't.

Any ideas of how to deal with such a case please? My DB is `Sybase`

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database. It would be helpful if you specify which Sybase product and version you are using (ASE, SQL Anywhere, IQ, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Why not check to see if there is any data there to start with like so:

```
if exists (select * from table1)
    Select * into table2 from table1
```

Comment: I tried this solution however it is not working as well. Are you aware if such a case is supported by Sybase?

Comment: I tried it in Sybase 11 and it worked fine. Not sure why it wouldn't work for you. @mzbib what error message are you receiving when trying this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IF` statement and `COUNT` function to check if rows exist in table.

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) >= 1)
BEGIN 
   SELECT * INTO table2 FROM table1
END
```

---

Or you can use `EXISTS` condition.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1)
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO table2 FROM table1
END
```

---

AS you said that you can't use `IF` statement you could try something like this:

```
INSERT * INTO Table2 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT (CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN col1 ELSE NULL END) AS col1,
       (CASE WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL THEN col1 ELSE NULL END) AS col2,
       (CASE WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL THEN col1 ELSE NULL END) AS col3
FROM Table1
```

Comment: I am afraid I cannot use the IF statment

Comment: Updated my answer with `CASE` try It and let me know If that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You got to use dynamic sql:

```
if object_id("table1") is not null
EXEC ("Select * into table2 from table1")
```

this code will pass compilation, none of the ones above will.

**2 others condition to succeed :**

1) the option `select into/bulkcopy/pllsort` must be on

2) I think that this capability has been added since `sybase 15.7 sp101`

==> issue select @@version to check your server version